# What exactly is a "witch"?

Tags: gundam-witch-from-mercury

In *Mobile Suit Gundam: The Witch From Mercury*, the title refers to Suletta Mercury, who is indeed referred to as a "witch" on numerous occasions. Sophie and Norea also specifically refer to themselves as "witches" during the attack on Plant Quetta.

At no point is it ever explained what a "witch" actually *is* within the context of the series. I can infer that it refers to

> artificial humans created for the purpose of piloting Gundams, as Suletta, Sophie, and Norea all are IIRC,

but it's possible I've misunderstood or am missing something. So what exactly *is* a "witch"?

Comment: This definitely seems like a translation issue. What's the Japanese word? "Suisei no Majo": Suisei is Mercury. So we're depending on Majo which I think means magic user. Since they're female, maybe that's why they're called witches. In Gundam, there's some idea of magic, so I'm wondering if it's related to that.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes I don't believe the *Witch From Mercury* continuity contains that sort of magic. The closest thing is Permet, the particles that allow Gundams to work, but that's more Clarkian magic than actual magic.

Comment: FYI, it seems a matter of speculation. [This](https://zundad.com/suiseino-majo-mean-definition/) says 魔女 stands for an existence controlling Gundams as demons. I'm not very familiar with the whole Gundam series, and don't know the plausibility of what the post says.